# RxJava2. Execute a request for every item in a list

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, rx-android, rx-kotlin

I have a list `List<FileModel>`

`FileModel` is just a class contains `id: Int`

`id` - is ID of photo file I need to fetch and cast to Bitmap

I have a request:

```
fun getFile(fileId: Int): Single<ResponseBody>
```

This request returns `ResponseBody` which we can cast to Bitmap

And

```
fun generatePhoto(responseBody: ResponseBody): Single<Bitmap?>
```

What I want is to create a function

```
fun getPhotos(list: List<FileModel>): Single<List<Bitmap>> {
    // Execute getFile(...) for each item in the list
    // Cast getFile(...) result to Bitmap using generatePhoto(...)
    // Return a list of Bitmaps
}
```

I've tried something like this but it's completely wrong

```
fun getPhotos(list: List<FileModel>): Single<List<Bitmap>> {
    return Observable.fromIterable(list)
        .flatMap { getFile(it.id) }
        // How to call generatePhoto(...) here?
}
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in Rx, could you provide an example?

Comment: Actually, it's probably just supposed to be flatMap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
fun getPhotos(list: List<FileModel>): Single<List<Bitmap>> {
    // Get an Observable of the list
    return Observable.fromIterable(list)
        // Get a Single<ResponseBody> for every FileModel
        .flatMapSingle { getFile(it.id) }
        // Get a Single<Bitmap> for every ResponseBody
        .flatMapSingle { file -> generatePhoto(file) }
        // Put everything back on a list
        .toList()
}
```

This way you can iterate over the list `flapMapping` for your needs and then putting it back together as a list in the end. The `toList()` operator is just a convenience that puts together the items emitted previously.

And to call this function just go:

```
    getPhotos(list)
        .doOnSuccess { resultList ->
          Log.d("Rx", "doOnSuccess.resultList=[$resultList]")
        }
        .subscribe()
```

By the way, if you have `RxKotlin` as a dependency you can get an `Observable` from a `List` with an extension function, like this:
`myList.toObservable()`

Answer (score 1):

Observable.fromIterable(list) should emit an event for each item in the list which means that you're return type in getPhotos be `Flowable<Bitmap>` as Flowable can return more than one value.

I think what you actually want is:

```
fun getPhotos(list: List<FileModel>): Flowable<Bitmap> {
    return Observable.fromIterable(list)
        .map { getFile(it.id) }
        .map { generatePhoto(it) }
}
```

if you want to emit a list of Bitmaps you can use single like this

```
fun getPhotos(list: List<FileModel>): Single<List<Bitmap>> {
    return Single.just(list)
        .map { it.map { getFile(it.id) } }
        .flatMap { 
            Single.just(it.map { generatePhoto(it) }) 
        }
}
```

Comment: But if we use Single.just(list) inside map { } we will have List<FileModel> instead of FileModel

Comment: i've updated the answer, you can iterate over each list inside of the map block

Comment: you can flatMap to evaluate the single but you have to emit another single in that case

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
fun getPhotos(list: List<FileModel>): Single<List<Bitmap>> {
    return Observable.fromIterable(list)
        .flatMapSingle { getFile(it.id) }
        .flatMapSingle { generatePhoto(it) }
}
```

?

Comment: We can't call flatMapSingle after flatMap

Comment: You're right, maybe it should be `flatMapSingle` on both.